# A set minus the set of its condensation points in a second countable space being non countable

Tags: general-topology

I'm having trouble proving the following statement: Assume X is a second countable topological space and let $A^c$ denote the condensation points of a given set, $A$ (i.e, those points such that for any neighbourhood of the point, the nbd intersection A is non countable). I want to prove that $A-A^c$ is non countable.

Comment: ?? What if $X=A=[0,1]?$

Comment: Other counter-examples: $X=A=\mathbb R,$ or $X=\mathbb R$  and $A=\mathbb R$ \ $\mathbb Q.$ In either case we have $A^c=X.$